# How to proxy methods on the prototype using ObjectProxy in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a simple ObjectProxy that I'd like to make calling methods on easy(er). For example, the object I plan to "proxy" has a method named foo and bar - they will not be available directly causing me to do something like this.

```
this.get("model").get("content").foo();
this.get("model").get("content").bar();
```

Instead I'd much prefer if foo and bar acted like they were on the object

```
this.get("model").foo();
this.get("model").bar();
```

I can make this happen (long hand) by hard coding the foo and bar methods on the ObjectProxy itself - then pulling content and invoking the method manually w/ apply like so

```
  return Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
        content: function() {
            var filter_value = this.get("filter_value");
            return this.get("source").filterBy("id", filter_value).objectAt(0);
        }.property("source.[]"),
        foo: function() {
            var content = Ember.get(this, 'content');
            return content["foo"].apply(content, arguments);
        },
        bar: function() {
            var content = Ember.get(this, 'content');
            return content["bar"].apply(content, arguments);
        }
    }).create({
        filter_value: id,
        source: store.find(type)
    });
```

If instead I wanted to proxy each "method" like this - how can I set the prototype in a way that won't hurt the tree that ember has built up already?

Comment: Can't one use ```this.get("model.content").foo();```?

Comment: Why don't you use a mixin for this? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: This is tricky, cause generally the object proxy is used for asynchronous objects.  That's the case here as well, right?

Comment: Correct about async usage - I'd be willing to do a guard clause of some kind of that's an option (making null or not resolved yet less problematic)

Comment: I've got a funny idea, give me a sec to write it up

Comment: @ToranBillups curious to know, your approach with [recordProxy](https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store/blob/master/addon/models/record-proxy.js) solves this, yeah?  Seems to me to be a slightly cleaner implementation by avoiding observers, though it's fundamentally the same idea.

Comment: @JamesConkling correct - the recordProxy you linked to is what I ended up building from this Q/A. The core idea was that I needed a "shell" of a model that could act as a proxy until the real model was available (after some async operation had finished). This abstraction (along w/ the core ObjectProxy itself in ember helped solve that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it's an idea, if you don't want to always define the functions.  To be honest, this wouldn't be a terrible idea of something to add to ember, I hate having to go two levels deeps to hit the functions.

#### Code Change

```
Ember.ObjectProxy.reopen({
  addFunc: function (content, method) {
    this[method] = function () {
      if (!content[method]) return;
      return content[method].apply(content, arguments);
    };
  },
  setupMethods: Ember.observer('content', function () {
    var content = this.get('content');

    if (!content) return;

    for (var item in content) {
      if (typeof content[item] == "function") {
        if (!this[item]) { // watch out for clashing names
          this.addFunc(content, item);
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

I think tracking the added methods, and possibly cleaning up after content changes wouldn't be a terrible thing, but I doubt a single object proxy often holds more than one underlying object.

#### Examples

```
var o = Ember.ObjectProxy.create();

console.log(o.foo);

o.set('content', {
  foo: function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
});

console.log(o.foo);

o.foo();

o.set('content',{
  bar: function(){
    console.log('bar');
  }
});

o.bar();
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/juwomezape/1/edit

The caveat being that, until the content is defined, no methods exist, but often we have resolved objects before we even start messing with them anyway.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for throwing down an idea to get me something to look at :)